# error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for PageCount

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration, codeplex

I migrated the opensurce project

http://surveymaster.codeplex.com

from MVC 2 to MVC 4

I have the followinng compiling errors now:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\SurveySession\Index.aspx(7,13): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'PageCount' and no extension method 'PageCount' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\SurveySession\Index.aspx(12,38): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Page' and no extension method 'Page' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\SurveySession\Start.aspx(22,34): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SurveyId' and no extension method 'SurveyId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\SurveySession\Start.aspx(23,30): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Questions' and no extension method 'Questions' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\SurveySession\Review.aspx(23,34): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SessionId' and no extension method 'SessionId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

the error is given on line 7:

```
Line 5:  </asp:Content>
Line 6:  <asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
Line 7:  <% if(Model.PageCount.Equals(0)) {%>
Line 8:  La moment nu sunt chestionare disponibile pentru dvs.
Line 9:  <%}%>
```

There is also source complete compilation souce if you need

Comment: do you have a model property having name PageCount???

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, Model properties are the ones on the right in this screenshot? https://db.tt/BH3WjnGH

Comment: there is no property with PageCount name that is why error is coming..@carni89..

Comment: @carni89....please upvote accept answer if answer helped you to solve your problem so that it will help others also..thankzzz...

Comment: have you tried building and running the unmodified solution ?

Comment: @Omu..yes..It gave me problem on the webUI that was not compatible with VS2012. That-s why I migrated from MVC 2 to 4

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your second image it appears that you are missing some of the classes in Assembly `Core.Model`. The view you are referring to uses `Core.Model.IPageable<Core.Model.SurveySession>` but you don't appear to have included `SurveySession.cs` in `Model.Core`. Check the [source code](http://surveymaster.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.txt) to ensure all required files and references are included.

Note: Using ASP server controls in MVC 2 was probably considered bad practice back then. Using them in MVC 4 is just awful and I strongly recommend you start from scratch.

Comment: I searched for only Pagecount elements here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17360312/pagecount.png so you cannot see SurveySession.cs. Here https://db.tt/8tdzM99j you can see all the classes of Model.Core

Comment: Your error _..'object' does not contain a definition for 'PageCount'.._ is suggesting that the model is not being referenced correctly - in particular note _..are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?_. I'm afraid that without looking at the whole code and all your references, I can't tell exactly where the problem is. Sorry but I don't have time to do that.

Comment: there's no ASP server controls in surveymaster

Comment: @carni89 if you're using web-forms viewengine and masterpage, you're gonna have asp:Content but there's no usage of controls like asp:Button , label etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the Views/Web.config file replace all the occurrences of

```
System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0
```

with

```
System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because there is no property with name `PageCount` in your model class and there is not any helper or `extenstion methods` in MVC named `PageCount` is there, just include `PageCount` property in your Model class or remove this line from your View and error will be removed.

Thank!!

Comment: It still doesn't work..I added PageCount to both Model folders that I have https://db.tt/OuNBs5Qn

Comment: @carni89..instead of making another class just add a property PageCount  in existing class only...